# Python: ¿Como hago para acceder AL NOMBRE de un diccionario?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una prueba con un "chatbot" que al detectar una palabra que no concoe te pida su significado o que responder, pero eso no importa ahora. La cuestion es que para probar, hice un diccionario llamado "words"

```
words = {"hola" : "Hey!"}
```

Lo que quiero es que al escribir "hola" responda "Hey!", entonces hice este if

```
c = input("> ") # Con esto se pide la entrada de texto al usuario
if (c == words.get("hola")):
    print(words.get("hola"))
```

¡Pero claro! Me di cuenta que eso solo funciona para acceder al significado del diccionario (osea que es "hola" es igual a "Hey!"). Eso significa que tengo que escribir "Hey!" para que me responda lo mismo que he puesto

¿Hay alguna manera de acceder solo al nombre?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres saber si una palabra es una clave válida en un diccionario, evaluas la expresión lógica

```
palabra in diccionario
```

Si la palabra es una clave válida, puedes recuperar el valor asociado usando

```
diccionario[palabra]
```

Con lo cual el código se simplifica:

```
words = {"hola" : "Hey!"}
c = input("> ") # Con esto se pide la entrada de texto al usuario
if c in words:
    print(words[c])
```

Comment: Gracias!! Funciono perfectamente, ahora tengo otra pregunta:

Comment: Quiero hacer que puedan haber varias respuestas, y que se elija una aleatoriamente ¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Mejor formula una nueva pregunta, para poder responder adecuadamente.

Comment: Ok estate atento porfavor!

Comment: Ya he publicado la pregunta